# using first gen frontrow remote with unibody macbook?

Tags: macbook, apple-remote

Has anybody tried using a first gen frontrow remote with a newer unibody macbook?  I'm assuming its IR?  Does the unibody macbook even support IR? I can't seem to get mine to recognize the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works ! Have you checked your remote preferences ?

[image]

- Make sure "Disable remote control infrared receiver" is unchecked
- Check also that you computer is not paired witch an other remote